# Cannot read property 'match' of undefined asp MVC Morris Chart

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, morris.js

Good day!

I'm currently working on a dashboard with a morrischart in it. The dashboard is made with ASP MVC.

With javascript i call a function in my controller that returns me my data.

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Diagram")', function (result) {
            console.log(result) #Has the the correct information
            Morris.Line({
                element: 'morris-area-chart',
                data: result,
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['ColliAantal'],
                labels: ['Colli aantal'],
                pointSize: 1.5,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                resize: true
            });
```

"Result" contains the json data i need for the chart.'

The code i show here is the controller code. scorebord is already defined and had the good data in it.

```
try
{
    List<ChartData> chartData = new List<ChartData>();
    foreach (Scorebord item in scorebord.Take(100))
    {
        chartData.Add(new ChartData(item.ColliQty, item.Datum));
    }
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartData); 
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

The weird thing is, if I go into debug and copy the data that is returned in the controller and past it in directly in the javascript as data, the thing suddenly works!

I hope someone can help me with this, probably simple, problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried to return your json var (only string) instead of an object of type Json?

Comment: According to the documentation JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartData) returns a string. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, try to return the string that is generated by the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartData) function

Comment: I just tried returning the string directly in the chart. It made no difference.

Comment: you should also set the datatype to 'json' in your javascript when your calling the controller action

Comment: Ow i feel so stupid! Thats it! i totally forgot to set the datatype to json! Thanks!